# seeking solution to set padding for multiple page with dynamic data in the jspdf

Tags: angular, pdf, jspdf

I am trying to set the padding for each page in the pdf but it did not get any solution on this

```js
async generatePdf() {
   const DATA = this.content.nativeElement; // html nativeElement
   const doc: jsPDF = new jsPDF('p', 'px', 'a4');

   doc.html( DATA, {
     margin: [40, 60, 40, 60], // trying to set the margin
     callback: function (doc) {
       doc.save('My_pdf');
     }
  })
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wq84t.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
async generatePdf() {
  var element: any = document.getElementById('htmlData');
  var opt = {
    margin: [30, 0, 30, 0], //top, left, buttom, right
    filename: 'test.pdf',
    image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 1 },
    html2canvas: { dpi: 192, scale: 2, letterRendering: true },
    jsPDF: { unit: 'pt', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait' },
    pageBreak: { mode: 'css', after: '.break-page' }
  };

  html2pdf().set(opt).from(element).toPdf().get('pdf').save();
}
```